# cannot import csv to sql because of missing values

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I am trying to import a very large csv (10000 rows+) and some of the rows have empty cells, this causes a problem because I get the error "Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'max_age' at row 2". There are a lot of these cells throughout and modifying the csv would take to long, is there a way to either ignore these rows, set them as null, or set them as 0 so that I can import this csv. Thank you so much.

LOAD DATA INFILE 'var/lib/mysql-files/pop.csv' INTO TABLE pop fields terminated by ',' ignore 1 rows;

Comment: Where does the CSV come from?  Get them to fix the problem.

Comment: I don't quite undestand, is that sepcific integer column set to `NOT NULL`? Or does the file contain values that are not integers, like `-` or `""` or `N/A` or something like that?

Comment: Welcome to SO, @tyler ! Please add table definitions. See  [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for any SQL query question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query). Please add some example lines from the csv.